# tell sql server to do a binary search?

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, search, binary-search

I kind of want to somehow instruct sql server to perform a search using a specific algorithm.

My scenario is something like I have a sorted list of words. I upload this to a database table. I'd want to search the table to find if the word exists. That's how far my requirement goes.

Is sql server designed for such a use case? If there are no such thing what are the options I have at my disposal to make the retrieval quick?

Comment: As long as you have an index on that column, either clustered or nonclustered, SQL Server will perform a binary search for you. You cannot make it faster than that in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server should already implement the fastest search possible against your data. In fact, if you create an index on that field you do a search for, you'll get even better results than binary search.

Comment: Can you please give an example how it will be faster than a binary search? We know to fetch records from an index, it will have to first read the index then it fetches the relevant row from the database table.

Comment: @JamshaidK. an example would be a hash-based index, esp if full-text search is already in place. Say there is a 256-way associative hash table used as index, in which entries are sorted. Then should you search for a value, SQL Server would first reduce the set in which to search for that value by using the exact part of index with matching "hash" then implementing binary search on that part. This would be a tad faster then performing binary search over the entire corpus of data (entire table).

Comment: That part I do understand, An index could be faster if the hash based index is being used. But, let's suppose, we have a table, we know the count of the records and we know our data inside the table is ordered, since, we had inserted it in order based on identity column. Cannot it be possible to just do a binary search and would not that be fast enough?

Comment: @JamshaidK. you mean if the table is NOT indexed? Or, if the field you look up and that's supposed to be sorted is NOT indexed? No, it's quite possible that SQL Server would not do a binary search then, because mostly databases are optimized towards fast CRUD not preferring either operation, that is, SQL Server does NOT assume the data in table is already sorted by any field, as new inserts could add different values and they had to be performed quickly enough to not lag the application. That's why you need those indexes to do fast selects.

Comment: I am completely in favor of using indexes. But I was just curious if this is possible, if it is or it is not, why?
The thing here is, is it not possible for a query to do a binary search instead of an index seek/scan to get the row? Ideally, when there is no index on the table, it does a table scan i.e bruteforces the search(at least that's what I think) which sometimes tends not to be efficient.

Comment: @JamshaidK. I say making SQL Server perform exactly a binary search on the table is not possible, due to the general nature of tables being unsorted while stored in the database, and due to SQL Server indexes providing better data access at the cost of extra storage.

Comment: Well, that is true, the storing is unorganized, sadly. Though I need to see if it is the same scenario with In-Memory OLTP as well.